# Datetime - How to display datetime local format depending on user location?

Tags: php, datetime

I am about to build calendar with DateTime class, i have to localize days name depending user localion (DE, US, FR ..).

```
// Date de debut
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_ES');
$today = new DateTime();
print_r($today->format('D'));
```

This snipet always print date in english, how to overcome this ?

Thank you

Comment: Hint: `$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);`

Comment: _“This snipet always print date in english, how to overcome this ?”_ - step 1: Go read up on the function you are using, and verify whether it is actually capable of what you want it to do in the first place! https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php: _“This method does not use locales. All output is in English.”_

Answer (score 1):

I found answer, pretty simple :

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_ES');
$today = new Datetime();
echo strftime("%A", $today->getTimestamp());
```

Thank all for your helps

Answer (score 0):

you can use javascript

```
  <button onclick="userDate()">Try it</button>

  <p id="test"></p>

  <script>
  function userDate() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.toLocaleString();   //this is what you need
 document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = n;
}
</script>
```